# Как реализовать такую css анимацию?

Tags: html5, css3, css-animation

```
     <div class="image">

</div>

    .image{
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    position:relative;
}
.image:before {
    content: '';
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 8vw 50vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
    z-index: 5;
}
.image:after {
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8vw 0 0 50vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
.image:before {
    -webkit-animation: flipOutRight 7s both ease-in;
    animation: flipOutRight 7s both ease-in;
    z-index: 1000;


}
.image:after {
    -webkit-animation: flipOutLeft 7s both ease-in;
    animation: flipOutLeft 7s both ease-in;
    z-index: 1000;


}
@-webkit-keyframes flipOutRight {
    0% {
        border-width: 0 0 8vw 50vw;

    }
    100% {
        border-width: 0 0 1000008vw 50vw;

    }
}
@keyframes flipOutRight {
    0% {
        border-width: 0 0 8vw 50vw;

    }
    100% {
        border-width: 0 0 1000008vw 50vw;

    }

}
@-webkit-keyframes flipOutLeft {
    0% {
        border-width: 8vw 0 0 50vw;

    }
    100% {
        border-width: 1000008vw 0 0 50vw;

    }
}
@keyframes flipOutLeft{
    0% {
        border-width: 8vw 0 0 50vw;

    }
    100% {
        border-width: 1000008vw 0 0 50vw;

    }

}

.image:before {
    -webkit-animation: e-flipOutRight 7s both ease-in;
    animation: e-flipOutRight 7s both ease-in;
    z-index: 1000;

}
.image:after {
    -webkit-animation: e-flipOutLeft 7s both ease-in;
    animation: e-flipOutLeft 7s both ease-in;
    z-index: 1000;


}
@-webkit-keyframes e-flipOutRight {
    0% {
        border-width: 0 0 1000vw 50vw;


    }
    100% {
        border-width: 0 0 8vw 50vw;

    }
}
@keyframes e-flipOutRight {
    0% {
        border-width: 0 0 1000vw 50vw;


    }
    100% {

        border-width: 0 0 8vw 50vw;
    }

}
@-webkit-keyframes e-flipOutLeft {
    0% {
        border-width: 1000vw 0 0 50vw;

    }
    100% {

        border-width: 8vw 0 0 50vw;

    }
}
@keyframes e-flipOutLeft{
    0% {

        border-width: 1000vw 0 0 50vw;

    }
    100% {
        border-width: 8vw 0 0 50vw;

    }

}
```

Есть набросок кода: https://jsfiddle.net/JohDak/k27hh1jm/1/
Анимация в примере проходит сначала медленно, затем все быстрее за счет того, что бордер задан в VH(это необходимо для адаптивности, в пикселях на мобильном не подстраивается) и он чем больше к краю, тем большее значение VH требует. Помогите реализовать эту анимацию плавно и равномерно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `ease-in` тебе нужно использовать другую `animation-timing-function` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp
Попробуй `cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1)`. А точнее подобрать параметры можно на этом сервисе: http://cubic-bezier.com

```css
.image:before {
    -webkit-animation: e-flipOutRight 7s both cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
    animation: e-flipOutRight 7s both cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.image:after {
    -webkit-animation: e-flipOutLeft 7s both cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
    animation: e-flipOutLeft 7s both cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
    z-index: 1000;
}
```